# Console.log statement is showing undefined when logging an AJAX/ JSON request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

This is the first time I've used AJAX, I am sure that other people have had this error but after lots of trying and searching I cannot find the answer. I am sure it is something simple. I'd appreciate any assistance.

```
// create variable for JSON request
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

// get request for tested JSON link
ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://api.fixer.io/latest');
ourRequest.onload = function () {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    console.log(ourData[1]);
};

ourRequest.send();
```

Comment: So it is showing as undefined when I run in the browser and check the console. I'm using Chrome

Comment: The api returns an object `{"base":"EUR","date":"2017-02-24",...` and not an array. -> [MDN: Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17x5cgfb/)

Comment: Is it a cross-origin request? What is `.responseText`? What is `.status`? What is `ourData` (not `ourData[1]`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ourData` is a JavaScript object and not an array.

I think by `ourData[1]` you want to get the date, so instead you need to do `ourData.date` or `ourData['date']`

```js
// create variable for JSON request
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

// get request for tested JSON link
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://api.fixer.io/latest');
ourRequest.onload = function () {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    console.log(ourData['date']);
    console.log(ourData.date);
};

ourRequest.send();
```

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since respoonse is in Json so you can use the following code and use whatever way you like

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

// get request for tested JSON link
ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://api.fixer.io/latest');
ourRequest.onload = function () {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    console.log(ourData['date']);
    console.log(ourData.date); //or you can write in this format
    console.log(ourData['base']);
    console.log(ourData.base);
    console.log(ourData['rates']);
    console.log(ourData.rates);
    console.log(ourData['rates']['AUD']);
    console.log(ourData['rates'].AUD);
};

ourRequest.send();
```